# Interactive filters set on page load only show up after manual refresh

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-20.2

I am setting up dynamic filters for the IG using new APEX_IG package method add_filter. So from Page 1 I click oin the link to go to Page 2 where I have interactive grid. Through that link I set a couple of page items on page 2 and based on those items I create filters using `APEX_IG.ADD_FILTER`. So the setting of the filters has to be done on PAGE_LOAD.

On page load I use a DA that calls `APEX_IG.ADD_FILTER` if a specific page item is not null. When I open the page first time, I do not see the filters applied, they only show up after I manually refresh the page. I added a refresh action for the IG after executing `ADD_FILTER` but that does not do anything - in order to see the change I still have to manually refresh the page.

I cannot add any refresh action or submit page action under page load since that will refresh the page repeatedly. What is the best way to programmatically refresh the page after applying or removing the filters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the issue is just on page load, you could add the call to `APEX_IG.ADD_FILTER` in a pre-rendering page process instead of a dynamic action. This works fine for me. This [blog](https://stefandobre.com/2020/03/14/apex-20-1-introduces-the-apex-ig-package/) also explains that a full page refresh is needed.

Comment: I cannot add it to page process since what happens is form one page I click on the link and set page items on the second page and on the page_load of second page I set the IG filters based on those items

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding why this can't be done on page load - could you put together a quick sample on apex.oracle.com base on the emp table ? I'd be happy to take a look

Comment: I don't think I have an active account on apex.oracle.com. It does work on page load but the filters only show up after I refresh the page. It does work if I do that in page processing but, unfortunately, that is not what I need

Comment: My guess is that it does not work because of the order of events. A dynamic action is only fired _after_ the page is rendered. So the pl/sql to apply the filter is executed after the report has been rendered and will not have any effect.

Comment: Can't get it to work. It is explained here that a page refresh is needed for proper rendering https://stefandobre.com/2020/03/14/apex-20-1-introduces-the-apex-ig-package/

Comment: thank you! That helped me figure out the issue

Comment: Mind sharing the solution ? I'm curious too

Comment: Not at all, just like the article says, I moved my code to pre-rendering and now all works well

Comment: can you make your comment an answer so I could accept it

Comment: Done I added the comment with the blog reference to the main solution.